# Custom authorization issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm testing some custom authorization without the default Entity Framework stuff.
I have created an "ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)" project using "Authentication type" = "Individual Accounts".
In *Program.cs* I have:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<CustomIdentityUser>, CustomUserStore>();
builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<CustomIdentityUser>()
    .AddUserStore<CustomUserStore>();
```

For the moment *CustomIdentityUser* is just an empty class.

*CustomUserStore* looks like this:

```
public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<CustomIdentityUser>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public Task<CustomIdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Use dummy user for now
        //return new Task<CustomIdentityUser>(() => new CustomIdentityUser());
        return new Task<CustomIdentityUser>(() => { throw new Exception("THIS DOES NOT HAPPEN!"); });
    }
    ...
```

(All other methods from *IUserStore* currently throws NotImplementedException.)

If I start the application, go the the login page, enter some credentials and click login I can see that *FindByNameAsync* in *CustomUserStore* is called. Good, it seems the application actually uses my custom user store to look for the user whose name I just entered.

But that's where my luck ends. The user interface seems to be waiting for the login to complete. The *Task* returned from *FindByNameAsync* doesn't seem to be started at all...why? I think that the caller should get *CustomIdentityUser* instance from it (and then probably call *GetPasswordHashAsync* in *CustomUserStore*).

Comment: I'm feeling a bit stupid now. Not sure why I waited for someone else to start the task...

Answer (score 0):

why do you return new task in **FindByNameAsync** , also **CustomUserStore**

should be for extending identity properties. in my opinion, creating a service for identity functionality and using dependency injection

create an interface with the name **IIdentity.cs**

```
public Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUserAsync(string id , UpdateUserVm updatedUser);
```

then the implementation class **IdentityService**

```
public class IdentityService : IIdentity
    {
        ...
        public async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUserAsync(string id, UpdateUserVm updatedUser)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            currentUser.PhoneNumber = updatedUser.PhoneNumber;
            return currentUser != null ? await _userManager.UpdateAsync(currentUser) : IdentityResult.Failed();
        }
    }
```

then register the service

```
service.AddScoped<IIdentity, IdentityService>();
```

in controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
       private readonly IIdentity _identityService;
       public AccountController(IIdentity identityService) =>
            (_identityService) = (identityService);
  
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfile(params)
        {
            ...
            await _identityService.UpdateUserAsync(params)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a quite different approach from my code. I might have to think a little about this.